# MySQL Trigger Execution Order

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, triggers

I have a table that has both an `After Insert` and an `After Update` trigger on it.  If I, both insert records and update records in a single command, in what order with the triggers fire?

Comment: What You mean "insert and update records in single command" - please, show one. Triggers from definitions working on rows (ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW) - I dont know, situation in which one query adding and updating one row in same time.

Comment: we are using .Net Commands and if that one command both Inserts and Updates rows which trigger would fire first, the Insert or the Update

Comment: can You show a some lines of code ?

Answer (score 0):

After building a test project I was able to get the Answer.  The triggers are fired in the order in which the rows are in the Table.  So if I had a table with an After Insert, After Update, and After Delete triggers, they would fire in the order the rows that are triggering them are in.  This was tested in MySQL 5.6.

Here is the Requested Sample

```
Public Function UpdateTriggerrecords(ByVal dt As DataTable) As Boolean
    Try
        Return PerformUpdate(dt, SETUPTriggerrecords_UPDATE(), SETUPTriggerrecords_INSERT(), SETUPTriggerrecords_DELETE(), False)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function

Private Function SETUPTriggerrecords_UPDATE() As MySqlCommand
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE tbltriggerrecords SET strDescription=@strDescription, intTestingValue=@intTestingValue " & _
                                "WHERE  idTriggerRecords=@idTriggerRecords")
    CreateTriggerrecordsParameters(cmd)
    CreateTriggerrecordsIDParameters(cmd)
    Return cmd
End Function

Private Function SETUPTriggerrecords_INSERT() As MySqlCommand
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbltriggerrecords(strDescription,intTestingValue) " & _
                                            "VALUES(@strDescription,@intTestingValue)")

    CreateTriggerrecordsParameters(cmd)
         Return cmd
End Function

Private Function SETUPTriggerrecords_DELETE() As MySqlCommand
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM tbltriggerrecords WHERE idTriggerRecords=@idTriggerRecords")
    CreateTriggerrecordsIDParameters(cmd)
    Return cmd
End Function

Private Sub CreateTriggerrecordsIDParameters(ByVal cmd As MySqlCommand)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@idTriggerRecords", MySqlDbType.Int32).SourceColumn = "idTriggerRecords"
End Sub

Private Sub CreateTriggerrecordsParameters(ByVal cmd As MySqlCommand)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@strDescription", MySqlDbType.VarChar).SourceColumn = "strDescription"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@intTestingValue", MySqlDbType.Int32).SourceColumn = "intTestingValue"
End Sub

Private Function PerformUpdate(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal cmdUpdate As MySqlCommand, ByVal cmdInsert As MySqlCommand, ByVal cmdDelete As MySqlCommand, ByVal capturePrimaryKeyValue As Boolean) As Boolean 
    If connMySQL Is Nothing Then
        connMySQL = New MySqlConnection(connstrMySQL)
    End If
    Using connMySQL
        If connMySQL.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            connMySQL.ConnectionString = connstrMySQL
            connMySQL.Open()
        End If
        trans = connMySQL.BeginTransaction
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("", connMySQL)
        cmdUpdate.Connection = connMySQL
        cmdUpdate.Transaction = trans
        cmdInsert.Connection = connMySQL
        cmdInsert.Transaction = trans
        If cmdDelete IsNot Nothing Then
            cmdDelete.Connection = connMySQL
            cmdDelete.Transaction = trans
        End If
        Try
            If capturePrimaryKeyValue = True Then
            AddHandler da.RowUpdated, New MySqlRowUpdatedEventHandler(AddressOf OnRowUpdatedMySQL)
            End If
            da.UpdateCommand = cmdUpdate
            da.InsertCommand = cmdInsert
            If cmdDelete IsNot Nothing Then
                da.DeleteCommand = cmdDelete
            End If
            da.Update(dt)
            If capturePrimaryKeyValue = True Then
                RemoveHandler da.RowUpdated, AddressOf OnRowUpdatedMySQL
            End If
            PerformUpdate = True
            trans.Commit()
        Catch ex As Exception
            trans.Rollback()
            PerformUpdate = False
        Finally
            If connMySQL.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connMySQL.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your code that results in a single SQL statement firing both an after insert and after update trigger on the same table? I understand that you're using .NET with a single command, but how does that reduce to a single SQL statement being processed by MySQL?

Comment: Comment may have been misunderstood.  I have updated my answer to include how I updated the data with one call and fired all three triggers

Comment: You aren't actually issuing a single SQL statement that performs multiple functions. MySQL triggers (after insert, after update, etc.) are executed when the individual SQL statements are executed. If the logic in your program is such that you call a function, and that function issues a SQL INSERT followed by a SQL UPDATE then the insert trigger will be fired before MySQL even knows about the update statement. The update trigger will be fired when the SQL UPDATE statement is executed by MySQL. The order of trigger execution is dependent on the order you issue the statements in your program.

Comment: That does not line up with what I was seeing when I tested it.  Using the .NET Data Adapter with an Insert, an Update, and a Delete command, and the MySQL table having a corresponding After Even Trigger, the triggers executed in the order in which they were in the Data Table that the Data Adapter was updating.  This might have something to do with how the Data Adapter is sending the commands to MySQL, but as far as my program is concerned it is one call the Database